# Chartjs does not render chart when set responsive option to true

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using chartjs version 1.02 for my report. I grab the example that from the documentation to render a simple line chart. While I am experiencing the options, I realized there is a very useful option(**responsive**) that can resize the chart automatically when resizing the browser. Before I put this option in the option object, chart can be rendered and everything works fine. After adding this "responsive" option, the chart stop rendering. I wonder if this option works with line chart or this option has to depend on other options that I missed.

Here is my code

```
           var data = {
                labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'My First dataset',
                        fillColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0)',
                        strokeColor: '#2D7CFA',
                        pointColor: '#FFFFFF',
                        pointStrokeColor: '#2D7CFA',
                        pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
                        pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
                        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
                    }
                ]
            };
            var options = {
                scaleFontColor: '#FFF',
                scaleLineColor: '#456A82',
                scaleFontSize: 10,
                tooltipFontSize: 10,
                tooltipTitleFontSize: 10,
                bezierCurve: false,
                pointDotStrokeWidth: 3,
                responsive: true // this breaks the chart
            };
            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the responsive option is set the width of the canvas is driven by the width of its parent. So make sure that the parent has a non-0 clientWidth. For example if the parent is floated and positioned relatively with the child canvas absolutely positioned, it's width collapses to 0 causing the canvas to have no size. There could be other ways this could happen, but to fix your problem you just need to ensure that the parent has a width (could be % too) of it's own.

Comment: And does anyone know *how* do make sure the parent has non-zero clientWidth? I've tried setting style width:100% and display:block in css, but it's still zero until after the chart is drawn.